# convert numeric field to time format in R

Tags: r

I need to convert a numeric field to time format in R

My numeric field is also a little dirty, but the data appears as

```
9,
1235,
1033,
```

Each number is the minutes past midnight. i.e. the number "9" is to be interpreted as "9 minutes past midnight".

I tried using `strptime(1122, format="%H.%M.")`

But I have an error. I get `NaN`

Please help.

Comment: Can you clarify whether 1235 should be interpreted as twelve hours and 35 minutes past midnight (i.e. 12:35PM), or 1,235 minutes past midnight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base version.  You need to make sure everything has 4 digits:

```
vec <- c(9, 1235, 1033)
vec.pad <- sapply(vec, function(x) paste0(c(rep(0, 4 - nchar(x)), x), collapse=""))
strptime(vec.pad, format="%H%M")
# [1] "2014-03-23 00:09:00" "2014-03-23 12:35:00" "2014-03-23 10:33:00"
```

Comment: @user3453272, so which is it?  Do you expect 1235 to be 1235PM or 1,235 minutes after midnight?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
> library(chron)
> x <- c(9, 1235, 1033)
> times(x / (24 * 60))
[1] 00:09:00 20:35:00 17:13:00
```

Comment: Gabor, you seem to be getting some funny times (8:35PM instead of 12:35?)?  Or am I missing something completely?

Comment: The question states that the numbers represent minutes past midnight, not HHMM.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Agree the language is confusing, but I think his statement can be interpreted either way (unfortunately completely ambiguous as 00:09 is both 9 minutes past midnight, as well as zero hours and nine minutes past midnight), and the attempted use of H and M (as well as just general likelihood) suggests time is in HHMM format.  I guess OP can clarify.

Answer (score 0):

POSIXct times are generated as GMT and I don't know a reliable way of preventing this:

```
> tim <- as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())+times*60
> tim
[1] "2014-03-22 17:09:00 PDT" "2014-03-23 13:35:00 PDT" "2014-03-23 10:13:00 PDT"
> tim <- as.POSIXct(Sys.Date(),tz="Americas/Los_Angeles")+times*60
> tim   # Any suggestions to improve this are welcome.
[1] "2014-03-22 17:09:00 PDT" "2014-03-23 13:35:00 PDT" "2014-03-23 10:13:00 PDT"
```

So I add back 7 hours to get Pacific Daylight time (local for me):

```
> tim <- as.POSIXct(Sys.Date() )+times*60+3600*7
> tim
[1] "2014-03-23 00:09:00 PDT" "2014-03-23 20:35:00 PDT" "2014-03-23 17:13:00 PDT"
```

You can get a character output that hides the fact that these are "GMT" locale times:

```
> tim <- as.POSIXct(Sys.Date() )+times*60
> format(tim, tz="GMT")
[1] "2014-03-23 00:09:00" "2014-03-23 20:35:00" "2014-03-23 17:13:00"
```

OR without the dates:

```
> format(tim, "%H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
[1] "00:09:00" "20:35:00" "17:13:00"
```

Comment: Since `as.POSIXct.Date` doesn't use the `tz` arg, here are a couple alternatives: `as.POSIXct(format(Sys.Date()), tz="GMT")`; `.POSIXct(unclass(Sys.Date())*86400, tz="GMT")`