# Convert numeric/string to time in r from imported excel

Tags: r, excel, time

I know that this question was asked many times in different variations (for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596971/convert-numeric-field-to-time-format-in-r) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43446109/how-to-convert-numeric-values-to-time-without-the-date)).

However, I still have problems with converting numeric/string to time.

My data set is an excel file which I imported, and looks like this:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(322, 322, 322, 322, 322, 322), Cue = c("F1", 
"F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5"), TimeComming = c("1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1"), Time = c("0.690210162037037", "0.69030296296296301", 
"0.69652906250000002", "0.70100131944444399", "0.70550445601851897", 
"0.71043541666666699"), Stime = c("1.0058333333330394E-3", "1.0986342592590459E-3", 
"7.3247337962960568E-3", "1.1796990740740032E-2", "1.6300127314815005E-2", 
"2.1231087962963024E-2")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .Names = c("ID", "Cue", "TimeComming", 
"Time", "Stime"))

df

# A tibble: 6 x 5
     ID Cue   TimeComming Time         Stime      
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>       <chr>        <chr>      
1  322. F1    1           0.690210162~ 1.00583333~
2  322. F1    1           0.690302962~ 1.09863425~
3  322. F2    1           0.696529062~ 7.32473379~
4  322. F3    1           0.701001319~ 1.17969907~
5  322. F4    1           0.705504456~ 1.63001273~
6  322. F5    1           0.710435416~ 2.12310879~
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
   ID Cue TimeComming     Time        Stime
1 322  F1           1 16:33:54 00:01:26.904
2 322  F1           1 16:34:02 00:01:34.922
3 322  F2           1 16:43:00 00:10:32.857
4 322  F3           1 16:49:27 00:16:59.260
5 322  F4           1 16:55:56 00:23:28.331
6 322  F5           1 17:03:02 00:30:34.366
```

Comment: What format is this?

Comment: In excel `Time` was defined in format cells as Time- type 13:30:55, Stime - Custom - type hh:mm:ss.000

Comment: The `Time` field seems to be a fraction of 24 hrs, while the `Stime` field is in minutes

Comment: Can't you define the columns as 'text' in Excel, to avoid funny Excel conversions when writing from Excel?

Comment: My problem is that while I "manage" to convert the columns into time, it gives me the same time for all the column. @Henrik even when I change it to `text`, I still get the same result.

Comment: Correction: `Stime` is `t*1000/86400` where `t` is in seconds. Make of that what you will.

Comment: @Rohit, doing this `as.POSIXct.numeric(as.numeric(df$Stime)*1000/86400,
                   origin = "1899-12-30", 
                   tz = "GMT")`, still gives me the same answer for all the column: `"1899-12-30 00:00:01 GMT"`

Comment: @DJV , you'll probably have to convert to `difftime` instead of `POSIXct`

Comment: `as.POSIXct(24 * 3600 * 0.690210162, origin = "2018-01-01", tz = "UTC")`.  Then use `format` to grab the time part.

Comment: @Henrik do you want to write it as an answer so I could tick you?

Comment: I could, but I still think this should be taken care of upstream in Excel. I don't quite understand how a column defined as 'text' in Excel would be converted when writing from Excel... ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not the one who makes the Excel files. If I could argue on the subject, I would've asked them to send me a csv files :)

Comment: OK! You may also use `data.table::IDateTime(24 * 3600 * as.numeric(df$Time))$itime`

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of arithmetic can generate the pieces for you:

```
time_since_midnight <- function(x, decimal_second = FALSE){
  hours <- x %/% 60
  minutes <- x %% 60

  seconds_since_last_hour <- minutes * 60
  minutes <- seconds_since_last_hour %/% 60
  seconds <- seconds_since_last_hour %% 60

  if (decimal_second){
    sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02.3f", hours, minutes, seconds)
  } else {
    sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, floor(seconds))
  }
}

df$Time <- time_since_midnight(as.numeric(df$Time) * 24 * 60)
df$Stime <- time_since_midnight(as.numeric(df$Stime) * 24*60, 
                                decimal_second = TRUE)
```

Comparing with other proposed solutions, not much of a difference in processing time:

```
df <- do.call("rbind", replicate(1000, df, simplify = FALSE))

library(microbenchmark)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
microbenchmark(
  posix = 
  {
    format(as.POSIXct(24 * 3600 * as.numeric(df$Time), origin = "2018-01-01", tz = "UTC"),
           format = "%H:%M:%S")
  },
  arith = 
  {
    time_since_midnight(as.numeric(df$Time) * 24 * 60)
  },
  lubridate = 
  {
    round(seconds_to_period(as.numeric(df$Stime) * 86400), 3)
  },
  data.table = 
  {
    data.table::IDateTime(24 * 3600 * as.numeric(df$Time))$itime
  }
)

Unit: milliseconds


       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
      posix 15.431598 15.611066 16.166188 15.737016 16.127330 20.280457   100   c
      arith  6.959072  7.006285  7.293416  7.057017  7.133262 13.945123   100  b 
  lubridate  4.476727  4.728041  6.464536  5.749277  6.044285 60.472758   100  b 
 data.table  1.329881  1.412430  1.529952  1.490874  1.557735  2.716651   100 a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate)

round(seconds_to_period(as.numeric(substr(df1$Time, 1, 20))*86400))
```

OR

```
round(seconds_to_period(as.numeric(gsub("~", "", df1$Time))*86400))
```

To get rid of the ~'s. Both give:

```
[1] "16H 33M 54S" "16H 34M 2S"  "16H 43M 0S"  "16H 49M 27S" "16H 55M 56S" "17H 3M 2S"
```

And for Stime:

```
round(seconds_to_period(as.numeric(gsub("~", "", df1$Stime)) * 86400), 3)

[1] "1M 26.904S"  "1M 34.922S"  "10M 32.857S" "16M 59.26S"  "23M 28.331S" "30M 34.366S"
```